# Dynamically Loaded Assembly - Settings & Communication

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly, appdomain

Ok so... I have a WPF application (let's call it `Launcher.exe`) which loads and executes another WPF application (let's call it `Loaded.exe`) dynamically using something like this:

```
Byte[] assemblyData;

using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)))
    assemblyData = reader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
MethodInfo method = assembly.EntryPoint;

if (method != null)
{
    Object instance = assembly.CreateInstance(method.Name);
    method.Invoke(o, null);
}
```

Now... the problem is that `Launched.exe` has its own settings in the file `Loaded.exe.config`, and it also uses them in bindings. For example:

```
Topmost="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Topmost, Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}}"
```

First question is, how can I make my dynamically loaded assembly properly load/bind/update and, more generally, use its own settings? I don't think it can handle this automagically...

Second question is: can `Loaded.exe` communicate with `Launcher.exe`? Let's say `Loaded.exe` needs some data that only `Launcher.exe` can retrieve... how can it ask for it? I think I need something like a proxy between the two assemblies, but I can't even figure out how to start coding this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supose you'll need to load a separate assembly with it's own .config file, no?
One way i do that is to load the assembly in a new AppDomain. You'll could deploy that assembly in a separate folder with all his needed references.

First setup the AppDomain, here you have a method:

```
AppDomain getAppDomainForAssembly(string assemblypath, string appdomainname) 
    {
        //this._assembly_file = AssemblyFile;

        string _assembly_file_name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(assemblypath);
        string _rootpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblypath);

        //this._assembly_class_name = AssemblyClassNameToInstance;
        AppDomainSetup _app_domain_info = new AppDomainSetup();
        _app_domain_info.ApplicationBase = _rootpath;
        _app_domain_info.PrivateBinPath = _rootpath;
        _app_domain_info.PrivateBinPathProbe = _rootpath;
        _app_domain_info.ConfigurationFile = _rootpath + @"\app.config"; //Here put the path to the correct .assembly .config file
        AppDomain _app_domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
            appdomainname, null, _app_domain_info);

        return _app_domain;
    }
```

Then get an instance of the object that executes the method on the assembly:

```
protected System.Reflection.Assembly _asm_resolve(string assemblyFile)
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);
    }

object getInstanceFromAppDomain(ref AppDomain appDomain, 
  string assemblyPath, string className = null) 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = _asm_resolve(assemblyPath);
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = assembly.EntryPoint;

            return appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyPath, method.Name);
        }
        else 
        {

            return appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyPath, className);

        }
    }
```

Even if we know the Object Type, we could create a method with generic type:

```
T getInstanceFromAppDomain<T>(ref AppDomain appDomain, 
 string assemblyPath, string className = null) 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = _asm_resolve(assemblyPath);
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = assembly.EntryPoint;

            return (T)appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyPath, method.Name);
        }
        else 
        {

            return (T)appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyPath, className);

        }
    }
```

And then, invoke the method on the created instance, wich is executing in the new appDomain:

```
void executeMethod(Type objecttype, string methodname, ref object instancedObject, object[] methodparams) 
    {
        objecttype.InvokeMember(
            methodname, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instancedObject, methodparams);
    }
```

You could use like this:

```
AppDomain newappdomain = getAppDomainForAssembly(filePath, "Loaded.exe.domain");
        object loadedexe_object = getInstanceFromAppDomain(ref newappdomain,
            filePath);

        //If you know the method name to call...
        executeMethod(loadedexe_object.GetType(), "methodname", ref loadedexe_object, null);

        //or get entry point...
        executeMethod(loadedexe_object.GetType(),
            _asm_resolve(filePath).EntryPoint.Name, ref loadedexe_object, null);
```

For the second question, you could use NamedPipes, Remoting, WCF... 
You need to implement interprocess communication on the same machine. 
Take a look at MSDN documentaion, code sample covering this scenario with WCF
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx

See this sample on CodeProject, using Remoting
[Inter-process communication via Remoting](http://tech.pro/tutorial/633/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp)

Comment: or some samples http://tech.pro/tutorial/633/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp